# Retrieving scalar data using .xsd dataset object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone suggest the best way to retrieve a scalar value when the site uses .xsd files for the data sets? I have such site where before I commit to a insert task I need to verify duplicates.

Back in the day one would just instantiate a new connection and command object and run the query through BLL/DAL - easy job. With this prepackaged xsd file that the Studio creates for you I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 0):

First, i would recommend to add an unique index in your database to ensure that it's impossible to create duplicates.

To answer your question: you can add queries to the automatically created TableAdapters:

- [How to: Create TableAdapter queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx)

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)

> TableAdapter with multiple queries
>
> Unlike standard data adapters, TableAdapters can contain multiple
>   queries to fill their associated data tables. You can define as many
>   queries for a TableAdapter as your application requires, as long as
>   each query returns data that conforms to the same schema as its
>   associated data table. This enables loading of data that satisfies
>   differing criteria. For example, if your application contains a table
>   of customers, you can create a query that fills the table with every
>   customer whose name begins with a certain letter, and another query
>   that fills the table with all customers located in the same state. To
>   fill a Customers table with customers in a given state you can create
>   a FillByState query that takes a parameter for the state value: SELECT
>   * FROM Customers WHERE State = @State. You execute the query by calling the FillByState method and passing in the parameter value like
>   this: CustomerTableAdapter.FillByState("WA").
>
> In addition to queries that return data of the same schema as the
>   TableAdapter's data table, **you can add queries that return scalar**
>   **(single) values.** For example, creating a query that returns a count of
>   customers (SELECT Count(*) From Customers) is valid for a
>   CustomersTableAdapter even though the data returned does not conform
>   to the table's schema.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The site already uses tabel adapters in this fasion and that is what drives me creazy. I've inherited this site and having hard time with this. As I've indicted, I'm used to code BLL and DAL by hand. The table has a unique index but it is not the particular field I need to verify duplicates. The table keeps track of printer toners based on printer. Printer is the primary key and there are toners black, yellow, etc. including ohter info such as printer manufacturer. User can add new mfg and I need to verfy that the mfg is unique.

Comment: ...cont. I ran into problems with insert/update tasks because apperantly adapter can't handle updates/inserts when multiple join ed query is used. So to just make this work I included the mfg in my toner table. I realize this violates the norlmalization rule...